# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007] on MS Server PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, oauth-2.0, file-get-contents

Hi im getting the following error, when making a post request  i am using a MS Server, MSSQL database and php for a Oauth2 Solution.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\Storage\Pdo.php:156 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\Storage\Pdo.php(156): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\ResponseType\AccessToken.php(84): OAuth2\Storage\Pdo->setAccessToken('02742b6cd16424e...', 'testclient', NULL, 1465910857, NULL) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials.php(58): OAuth2\ResponseType\AccessToken->createAccessToken('testclient', NULL, NULL, false) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\Controller\TokenController.php(205): OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials->createAccessToken(Object(OAuth2\ResponseType\AccessToken), 'testclient', NULL, NULL) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\Controller\TokenController.php(49): OAuth2\Controller\TokenController->grantAccessToken(Object(OAuth2\Request), Object(OAuth2\Response in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\OAuth2\Storage\Pdo.php on line 156

After doing some research i understand the 22007 is related to a date problem, i have changed the formatting of the date.

Here is the code block from the Pdo.php the server is complaining about

```
public function setAccessToken($access_token, $client_id, $user_id, $expires, $scope = null)
{
    //convert expires to datestring
    //$expires = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $expires);
    $expires = date("Ymd H:i:s", $expires);
    //echo $expires . "-------------------";

    // if it exists, update it.
    if ($this->getAccessToken($access_token)) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare(sprintf('UPDATE %s SET client_id=:client_id, expires=:expires, user_id=:user_id, scope=:scope where access_token=:access_token', $this->config['access_token_table']));
    } else {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare(sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (access_token, client_id, expires, user_id, scope) VALUES (:access_token, :client_id, :expires, :user_id, :scope)', $this->config['access_token_table']));
    }

    return $stmt->execute(compact('access_token', 'client_id', 'user_id', 'expires', 'scope'));
}
```

The strange thing is in the terminal and postman when i run a curl post, i get the correct response when i run the request on token.php.

There is a problem with the php_curl.dll on our server which has meant i have to use file_get_contents post request to get the data.

```
public function getAccess() {
    $postdata = http_build_query ( array (
            'client_id' => 'testclient',
            'client_secret' => 'testpass',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' 
    )
     );

    $opts = array (
            'http' => array (
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata 
            ) 
    );

    $context = stream_context_create ( $opts );

    $result = file_get_contents ( 'http://IPADDRESS/api/token.php', false, $context );
    // var_dump($result);
    echo $result;
    return $result;
}
```

Im guessing the problem is related to using file_get_contents, as the access token is created from terminal and postman.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The value is out of the field type range

Comment: I have changed the date formatting and the current formatting allows the token to be created with postman and from terminal/command line